# How to repalce column values using pandas , based on the words present in the cell

Tags: python, pandas

My df looks like ,

```
   S2PName          S2PName-Category    
0   IDLY                    Food    
98  IDLY 4 PARCEL           Food    
99  IDLY 2 PARCEL           Food    
100 IDLY 5 PARCEL           Food    
101 IDLY 3 PARCEL           Food    
114 IDLY 6 PARCEL           Food
```

I would like to have my df as

```
   S2PName          S2PName-Category    
0   IDLY                    Food    
98  IDLY PARCEL             Food
```

So i need to check for the words 'IDLY' **and** 'PARCEL' , irrespective of the number in between, and then rename as IDLY PARCEL , how can i achieve this using pandas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `replace`

```
df.replace('IDLY\s+\d+\s+PARCEL', r'IDLY PARCEL', regex=True)

         S2PName S2PName-Category
0           IDLY             Food
98   IDLY PARCEL             Food
99   IDLY PARCEL             Food
100  IDLY PARCEL             Food
101  IDLY PARCEL             Food
114  IDLY PARCEL             Food
```

More generic

```
df.replace('(\w+)\s+\d+\s+(\w+)', r'\1 \2', regex=True)

         S2PName S2PName-Category
0           IDLY             Food
98   IDLY PARCEL             Food
99   IDLY PARCEL             Food
100  IDLY PARCEL             Food
101  IDLY PARCEL             Food
114  IDLY PARCEL             Food
```

Comment: and `drop_duplicates` to remove duplicates as op wants

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```python
df = df.replace(to_replace ='^IDLY.*PARCEL$', value = 'IDLY PARCEL', regex = True)
```